# Can't get the adapter of the Dialogfragment

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I Created class named Popupdialog which extends `DialogFragment`. So there is a recyclerview and adapter in that Popupdialog class.but when I am calling `((MyRecyclerViewforsmallcardincart)adapter).getmDataset();` from the activity ,I am getting `NullpointerException`.I know that the adapter is not going to the `DialogFragment` instead its uses its own adapter.How to overcome from this `NullpointerException`.
adapter in the `DialogFragment`

```
adapter=new MyRecyclerViewforsmallcardincart(activity,data);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Error part of the activity

```
dataset=((MyRecyclerViewforsmallcardincart)adapter).getmDataset();
                int o=((MyRecyclerViewforsmallcardincart)adapter).getdatasize();
```

actually the problem is that the activity and dialog fragment had individual adapter. how can I able to pass the adapter to Dialog fragment?

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                PopupDialog dialogFragment = new PopupDialog();
                dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
                dialogFragment.show(fm, "Color picker")
```

this is what I used to call `DialogFragment`.Thanks in advance

Comment: @BobMalooga it is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is, actually. EVERY NullPoiterExceprion has **the same origin**: a reference to a null object.

Comment: @BobMalooga ok.I admit that.But If the solution is different,How comes the question is a duplicate?.

Comment: It's a duplicate due to its nature: an NPE. **Every NPE has the same origin and the same solution**: find the null reference and fix **that**.

Comment: @BobMalooga But the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) never solves my problem. Also anyone who faced this kind of problem will never find the actual answer.

Comment: The juice, as I said, is: `Find and resolve your reference to a null object`. And that is.